# Multitasking gesture slower when using Nova Launcher

Tags: samsung, nova-launcher, gestures

I recently switched my Galaxy S23 from on-screen buttons to gesture navigation. I noticed that using the stock launcher I can open the multitasking screen very quickly when swiping upwards and holding (it takes about 0.5 seconds). When I set Nova Launcher as my default launcher and open its home screen, opening the multitasking window takes about twice as long, almost a whole second. When opening the stock launcher again it works fast like before.

This is very annoying as it heavliy hinders my workflow. I tried adjusting Nova's gesture settings but was unable to resolve the issue. How can I fix this?

Comment: I too use Nova on a Pixel device and have similar observations - this is because the launcher APIs are not freely available for integration with Nova//With Pixel, they at least have a companion tool that helps some

Comment: [**Does Nova Launcher support system gesture navigation?**
This isn't up to Nova Launcher, or any 3rd party launcher, but up to the system. If your system does not allow you to enable gesture navigation when using a 3rd party launcher, unfortunately there is nothing Nova Launcher can do about that](https://novalauncher.com/faq)

Comment: Please lodge a support request with them.